# TSQL :Resolving OVERLAPPING Date ranges for two sets of records giving priority to 1 set over another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are Multiple delays within ONE activity. Delays can be placed at the Boundaries and many can exists inside one Long activity. We need to give preference to DELAY records, thus we should disregard any activity records which appear inside a Delay record

I have two sets of records in one table namely ACTIVITY and DELAY for a particular machine in a particular shiftdate and shift.  During some shiftdates and shifts OVERLAP occurs between Acitivty and Delay .The DELAY records occurring between ACTIVITY records should be given the priority and ACTIVITY records should split accordingly around DELAY records thus removing the OVERLAP between Activity and Delays

What approach should I use to break up Activity records based on delay and give priorities to DELAY over activity records.

[image]

The code for creating table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Activity_Delays](
    [Type] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Shiftdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Shift#] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MachineID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Activity', CAST(0x0000A13B00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A13900735B40 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1390083D600 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13B00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A1390083D600 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A139009450C0 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A13900761A60 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1390078D980 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A139007B98A0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A139007FB750 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A13900815D30 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1390084A8F0 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A1390087F4B0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A139008C1360 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A13A0071B560 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A00761A60 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A13A007B98A0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A007FB750 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A13A0087F4B0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A008C1360 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A13A008D72F0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A008FA570 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A13900761A60 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1390078D980 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A139007B98A0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A139007FB750 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A13900815D30 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1390084A8F0 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A1390087F4B0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A139008C1360 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A13A0071B560 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A00761A60 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A13A007B98A0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A007FB750 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A13A0087F4B0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A008C1360 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Delay', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A13A008D72F0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A008FA570 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Activity', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A13900735B40 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1390083D600 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Activity', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A1390083D600 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A139008ED280 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Activity', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A13A00735B40 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A0083D600 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Activity', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'780', CAST(0x0000A13A0083D600 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A008ED280 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Activity', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A13900735B40 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1390083D600 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Activity', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A1390083D600 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A139008ED280 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Activity', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A13A00735B40 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A0083D600 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Activity_Delays] ([Type], [Shiftdate], [Shift#], [MachineID], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (N'Activity', CAST(0x0000A13A00000000 AS DateTime), 1, N'781', CAST(0x0000A13A0083D600 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13A008ED280 AS DateTime))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do, how are you trying to do it, and what do you think is going wrong when you do?

Comment: At the boundaries of what? You need to specify a lot more information explicitly before this becomes answerable. You've only shown code how to build the input (or underlying) data, can you show what you want out of whatever it is you want help with? Right now your "question" is like "I have this..." and then it ends.

Comment: Also note that SQL is very good at retrieving data, it is not so good at producing data that hasn't been stored in the database in the first place, which means that SQL might not be a good fit for your problem.

Comment: I have done many approaches to achieve a proper execution time for this kind of tasks. Please see [my post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31012/query-optimization-time-intervals) for more details which could help you in my opinion!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query for your example output:

```
select *, Activity_Delays.StartTime SortStartTime
from Activity_Delays
where 
   Type = 'Delay'
union all
select distinct Activities.*, Delays.StartTime SortStartTime
from
 Activity_Delays Delays
 inner join Activity_Delays Activities on Activities.ShiftDate = Delays.ShiftDate and
                                      Activities.MachineID = Delays.MachineID and
                                      ((Delays.EndTime between Activities.StartTime and Activities.EndTime) or
                                      (Delays.StartTime between Activities.StartTime and Activities.EndTime))
where
  Activities.Type = 'Activity' and
  Delays.Type = 'Delay'
order by MachineID, ShiftDate, SortStartTime, 1 desc
```

Also here is [an working output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9bd62/43)

Comment: The Output by this query does not break the Activity records . For instance Activity should be 7AM to 7:10 AM

Comment: I see, is it ok to change it to a proc or you want one single query?

Comment: I am trying to use a lot CTEs, but is there any advantage of a Stored proc. Are you hinting on using Cursors . Normally I try to do set based sql.

Comment: For this scenario its better to use Stored proc, I would use a loop instead of cursors.